# For the given functions $f$ and $g$, find $(g\circ f)(x)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$f(x)=4x^2+4x+6; g(x)=4x-4$

I have always had troubles with functions and need some help solving this one. I have been working on it for too long now and thought that maybe someone else's perspective would be better. I simply don't understand the path to solving it. If someone could walk me through the process that would be much appreciated.

Comment: $4f(x)-4{}{}{}$

Comment: Hi Thurbad, next time you ask a question you should state what you're troubling with, so we could help you better. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more intuitive way of writing $(g \circ f)(x)$ is $g(f(x))$. This just means that you write the function $g$ with $f(x)$ instead of $x$ inside the parentheses. Since
$$
g(\text{something}) = 4 \cdot \text{something} - 4 
$$
(which gives us $g(x) = 4x - 4$), just putting something = $f(x)$ gives
$$
(g \circ f)(x) = g(f(x)) = 4(f(x)) - 4 = 4(4x^{2} + 4x + 6) - 4 = \text{blah} 
$$

Comment: +1: Lovely explanation! Understanding that the input of a function is completely arbitrary is key to understanding them properly.

Comment: Thank you! I completely understand how to answer these now. Your explanation was priceless

Answer (score 1):

$$ (g\circ f)(x)=g(f(x))=4f(x)-4=4(4x^2+4x+6)-4=16x^2+16x+20$$